Normal force and when does it cancel out

If i have this box, making a turn and there is tennis ball inside, then how in terms of forces can the tennis ball stay how i drew it, all the way around the circle? What provides the centripetal force for that? I got told that the normal for between it and the wall is what does that but i dont understand how. Firstly if its the normal force that means the tennis ball exerted a force on the box wall, and so the box wall exerted an equal and opposite force on the ball. But i read that there is no such force and that its all inertia... so how does that make sense? Also in terms of calculations how would the centripetal force for the box be calculated? If i say that the tennis ball does exert a force on the wall, then wouldnt the centripetal force of the box be T + that force?
Also if the tennis ball does exert a force, then where does inertia come in?

See inertia.

Voting to reopen. Obviously a conceptual question and not at all "homework-like".

Where did you read there is "no such force" from the box on the ball? Please give a link.


But i read that there is no such force and that its all inertia...

This statement is partly correct. Newton's first law states that an object continues in a straight line or remains at rest if there are no external forces acting on the object. This is basically a statement about inertia. The ball 'wants' to continue in a straight line up the page and resists being accelerated. A force has to be applied to it, to make it follow the curved path to the left. We call this force the centripetal force which in this case comes from the tension in the string and the normal force of the box wall acting on the ball. What is not true in the statement is that there is no such force (as centrifugal force). Centrifugal force exists in an accelerating reference frame. If you were inside the box, it feels as if there is a force field accelerating any loose objects to the right. Inside the box with no windows you don't see yourself as travelling in a circle. You simply see the ball as stationary. Since you measure a force accelerating things to the right and the ball is stationary, you conclude that there must be an equal and opposite force being exerted on the ball by the wall (the centripetal force). The reactionary centripetal force is real. You can see the wall is being bent outwards by the wall and the intermolecular forces inside the wall are trying to accelerate the ball to the left.
